# UITableView Scroll w/ keyboardWillShow

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have uitableview scrolling upwards when keyboardWillShow event occurs. tableview is 320x148 and placed at the bottom of the uiview. When a user selects the first uitextfield, nsnotifcation is fired and moves the textfield accordingly.

My problem is, I have a label and logo in the background (uiview) that i want to see move upwards with the "event". I can do this with an animation, but it's not the desired effect.

My guess is to somehow make uiview move with uitableview somehow. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Humm, i think you could put your UITableView inside a UIScrollView. When the UITableView scrolls, you could do the same to the UIScrollView behind..

Comment: UITableView is a UIScrollView.http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html